# How do I add the profile parameter to the content-type header in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to set the `content-type` of my `HttpClient` Post request, and use the profile parameter, but when I change the content type I get an exception thrown:

> "The format of value 'application/json; profile={*URL HERE*}' is
>   invalid."

For reference, I found this Q&A: [Zoopla Sandbox with cURL http header error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355916/zoopla-sandbox-with-curl-http-header-error)

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("cert.pfx", "PASSWORD");
WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
var client = new HttpClient(handler);                
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://realtime-listings-api.webservices.zpg.co.uk");
var stringContent = new StringContent(propertyData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json; profile=http://realtime-listings.webservices.zpg.co.uk/docs/v1.1/schemas/listing/list.json");
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
var response = await client.PostAsync("/sandbox/v1/listing/list", stringContent);
return _resultFactory.Create(true, await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create a **HttpRequestMessage** and use client.**SendAsync()**, you can add the parameters to request.Content.Headers.ContentType.Parameters

```
var client = new HttpClient();
using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://realtime-listings-api.webservices.zpg.co.uk/sandbox/v1/listing/list"))
{
    request.Content = new StringContent("propertyData", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    request.Content.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(
        new NameValueHeaderValue("profile", "http://realtime-listings.webservices.zpg.co.uk/docs/v1.1/schemas/listing/list.json")
        );
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    //Handle response..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `HttpRequestMessage` but you do need to add the profile value as a quoted string via the NameValueHeaderValue parameter:

```
var content = new StringContent(request.ToJson(), Encoding.UTF8);
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
content.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("profile", "\"https://realtime-listings.webservices.zpg.co.uk/docs/v1.2/schemas/listing/update.json\""))
httpClient.PostAsync("listing/update", content);
```

This will get round the `FormatException`. Otherwise you will run into [this dotnet bug](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1504).